# Way to avoid chain of gestures to test iPhone App code often

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Suppose an application runs fine. But now app is in a phase of adding functionality to it. Assume programmer added functionality to one button which is visible after applying many gesture on iPhone.

(for example, tap one of the tabs then, tap one of the tableview cells visible thereafter, then few more taps & say on Navigation bar one button is visible to which programmer added functionality ).

So while testing functionality of that button, programmer has to tap the iPhone many times to goto that specific button.
If that added functionality is critical & needs to be tested many times then it would be tedious process of just reaching that button which may lead to some frustration.

So is there any tool available that will help user in skipping this chain of tappings on iPhone.

Or is there any other way to test such an app.

Comment: Has anyone used MonkeyTalk http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk

Comment: I think Xcode's "unit testing" was designed for this. See [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/01-Unit-Test_Overview/overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH2-SW1]. Personally, I'd rather tap amateurishly away. But if you're brave enough to try unit testing out, you could post some details in an answer for us more timid folk.

Comment: I am little more than junior iOS developer, so first let me read out the link you provided & see if i could something like that.  My app fetches huge amount of data not just at the time of login but also while using the app(its financial app involves coredata- sqlite,  xml-parsing & a/c refresh every 2 minutes & many more). So in a need of way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Instruments with UIAutomation, which lets you script UI actions, log messages and take screenshots. The test scripts are written using Javascript (search for UIAElement to find the API reference).

But the best resource to get you started is the WWDC 2010 session "Automating User Interface Testing with Instruments".

You should also read the [Accessibility Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html) since UI Automation leverages on that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't neglect the preprocessor constants as well. Something like:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // Some code to automatically skip the view controllers leading to this
#else
    // Production code
#endif
```

Otherwise I would investigate the UIAutomation classes for automating input to an iOS application. Furthermore, you should be Unit Testing the code *behind* your buttons. Writing a unit tests that pushes a button will always work. It's really rather pointless to unit test the framework code.

Comment: okk. thanks for reply. I will take good care of those preprocessor statements.