# Any mature solution of automatic testing for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, automated-tests

I am quiet new for this topic as iOS developer instead of QA. Is that possible to build the automatic testing for the iOS apps in the real devices ? If yes, any mature solutions ?

Comment: [Zucchini](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/) is pretty nice.

Comment: I wouldn't call those mature, although I use MonkeyTalk, and Zucchini looks nice, too. UIAutomation is more mature, FWIW.

Comment: u can look for this question for more description [Way to avoid chain of gestures to test iPhone App code often](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535164/way-to-avoid-chain-of-gestures-to-test-iphone-app-code-often)

Comment: @YusufX: Right you are w.r.t. maturity. That said, Zucchini (and others, perhaps?) is just a wrapper around UIAutomation -- one that I've found makes testing quite a bit less painful.

Answer (score 2):

I like [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF).

Easy to use and it lets you write your tests in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about mature solutions, but [Telerik's Test Studio for iOS](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/ios-testing/ios-application-testing.aspx) is something you might investigate even though it's in beta. (Disclaimer: I work for Telerik and help promote these tools.)

We work on the native device with no jailbreaking required. There's also no requirement for tethering or wifi/network connectivity, so you can work in a completely disconnected mode to ensure your apps' offline usage works properly. Test Studio for iOS also avoids messy positional-based locators, so it's nicely flexible. It works with native apps (UIKit), web apps, and hybrid apps too.

Comment: Can a Test Studio iOS test suite be integrated with CI (Jenkins etc.)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Yes, Test Studio for iOS can be used with a CI runner!